# Django aggregate Min on filtered reverse foreign field

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys, aggregate

```
class Order(models.Model):
    ...

class OrderApplication(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    driver = models.ForeignKey(Driver, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    suggested_price = models.DecimalField(..., blank=True, null=True)
```

I have the models as described above. All Orders usually have more than 1 OrderApplication (OA). However, there is only 1 OA for each Order which has a non-null `suggested_price` field.
At some moments I have to serialize a list of Orders and send it to the front-end React app.
I want my orders to be placed in a very specific Order:

1. For each order I want to get the OA which relates to it and have a non-null `suggested_price` field
2. Then when I get this OA I want to check its `created_at` field
3. Basing on this field the earlier the OA was created the closer to the end should the Order be placed. So, the first Order will be the one which has an OA with specified `suggested_price` and created as recently as possible

What I have already tried is ordering the Orders by the first created OA related to it:

```
.annotate(suggestion_created=Min('orderapplication__created_at')).order_by("-suggestion_created")
```

Here inside `Min` aggregator I use a reversed foreign relation of the Order which is can be accessed as `orderapplication` and get the first date of the objects which are in this reversed relation.
However, the problem is that it is not always true that the first OA related to any Order has `suggested_price` specified (even though it's the most common case), it may be the 2nd, the 3rd or something else.
I have also tried using `filter` parameter of the `Min`, however, it turns out that this filter is applied to the Orders themselves, but not to the reversed relation.
What I see as a possible solution is to use some aggregation function which can filter reversed relation, however, I haven't found one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter on the `orderapplication` as well:

```
from django.db.models import Q

Order.objects.annotate(
    suggestion_created=Min(
        'orderapplication__created_at',
        filter=Q(orderapplication__suggested_price__isnull=False)
    )
).order_by('-suggestion_created')
```

Or you can simply put this in the `.order_by` clause. If there is no such `orderapplication` the value will be `NULL`, you thus should decide if you want the `NULL`s to be *first* or *last*:

```
from django.db.models import Q

Order.objects.order_by(
    Min(
        'orderapplication__created_at',
        filter=Q(orderapplication__suggested_price__isnull=False)
    ).desc(nulls_last=True)
)
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but this filter would exclude those Orders which has no OA with non-null `suggested_price` and then for each order in the remaining list get the date of the earliest created OA related to it. However, it is possible that the earliest created OA will not have `suggested_price` specified and so the ordering will be wrong

Comment: @VladimirVislovich: no, it will still include these. As specified, then `Min(...)` is `NULL`. You can specify with `nulls_first` or `null_last`.

Comment: @VladimirVislovich: but perhaps I misunderstand you question? Given there is no OA (or no OA with a non-null price), then how should these be ordered?

Comment: There is always an OA with `suggested_price`, however, it is not always the earliest created one. So, lets say we have an Order and 2 OAs related to it. First one was created yesterday and has no `suggested_price`, the 2nd one was created today and has `suggested_price`. As long as I understand the filter, this Order will be included (since it has an OA with `suggested_price` related to it) and it will be aggregated with `Min`. However, what I suspect is that the `Min` will return the date of the OA created yesterday, not the today one.

Comment: @VladimirVislovich: no, in that case it will return the one today, since that is the first one that *satisfies the filter* condition.

Comment: Why is it the first one? I mean, the ordering of the OAs may be so that the earliest come in the end, and the oldest in the beginning. So the first one will be the oldest, yesterday one

Comment: @VladimirVislovich: because we use the `Min`imum of the `created_at`s for which the `orderapplication` has as `suggested_price` a non-NULL value.

Comment: @VladimirVislovich: perhaps you should try a few cases and check if the queryset is the one you are looking for.

Comment: Well, you was right. I tried and that works, even tough I do not completely understand it